# php-fpm returning empty response to nginx

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

nginx is connecting to php-fpm over fastcgi, using the standard `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` in the location block.

When connecting to /.status (php-fpm.ini::ping.path) from the command line with `cgi-fcgi -bind`, the result comes back as expected (X-Powered-By set, response body, etc).

When requesting with nginx, the result comes back empty (X-Powered-By set, no body length or content). nginx returns 200, since it got a "valid" response.

Watching over tcpdump, I've isolated the requests to parity in their FCGI headers (minus user-related env variables still set by the shell.)

Comment: Try changing to the user nginx runs as, and rerun the cgi-fcgi -bind test.

Comment: I always screw up NRPE deployments by testing them as root... figured you might have done the same.

Answer (score 12):

The standard `factcgi_params` file doesn't contain the key line for `SCRIPT_FILENAME`.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Add it and restart nginx.

Answer (score 5):

Well, your question is a bit vague. A so called “white screen of death” (WSOD) might be triggered by an endless amount of things. But some things I do if I encounter this:

- Activate the following in your `php.ini`:

  ```
  display_errors = 1
  display_startup_errors = 1
  error_log = /path/to/file
  error_reporting = -1 ; (the -1 activates absolutely everything)
  log_errors = 1
  ```
- Activate in your `php-fpm.conf`:

  ```
  error_log = /path/to/file
  ```
- Activate for each php-fpm pool configuration:

  ```
  catch_workers_output = 1
  ```
- Repeat your request and check all logs (incl. nginx error log)
- Increase logging level (e.g. debug on nginx)

If nothing of this helps you to pin-down the problem then please post your complete system information and configurations. Nobody is able to give you a precise answer without that.